# How to pass c sharp List Object into java script function?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried it like that but the JS function doesn't invoke

initial:

```
@{   
    List<CmsSite.Models.Category> category_list = (List<CmsSite.Models.Category>)ViewData["categories_details"];
}
```

pass to js function:

```
<button onclick="InsertNewProduct(@Json.Encode(category_list))">Save</button>
```

js function:

```
function InsertNewProduct(arr) {

    json_obj = {
                   //what to do here
    }
```

now arr is an array of JSON objects

I can't see the `List<CmsSite.Models.Category> category_list` values

How should I decode this on JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in following way:

```
@Json.Encode(category_list)
```

Upd:

```
<script>
    function testFunc(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            alert(arr[i]);
        }
    }
</script>

<button onclick="testFunc(@Json.Encode(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }))">
    Save
</button>
```

If this don't work for you there may be problems with your model class (`CmsSite.Models.Category`) serialization.

Comment: Had no idea MVC just came with this. Good stuff.

Comment: i have edit the quastion, now i am getting an aray of objects

Comment: I tried this with List and this works just fine. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The client won't see `category_list` because that's server-side code and isn't delivered. You could use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize the list into JSON and output that to a Javascript variable, or hidden field to reference with JavaScript.

The following should output the thing, just find a place to put it:

```
@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(category_list))
```

So, if you do this in a `script` block that will be rendered on the client, assign the output of that call to a variable and then it's present when the page is loaded.

Comment: i have edit the quastion, now i am getting an aray of objects